# iOS simulator view controller black background Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I run my app on the iOS simulator on Xcode, I get a black background on my initial view controller, but it still shows the the textfields and buttons. All the other functions work as well. I looked for other solutions and the solutions I found only apply to a complete black screen. I tried resetting the simulator, checked the Deployment Info, and the whatever solution I came across, but it did not fix the problem.

This is what happens when I run the app:
[image]

If there is a ways to fix this problem, the help would be appreciated.

Comment: check you view background color might be set to black.

Comment: I did not set my background black. I did not change the background color

Comment: try self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor]; in viewDidLoad method see what happen.

Comment: Create a new sample project and see if you find same issue or not. if your find the same issue, than share your sample project .

Comment: I made the copy of the file before I made changes to it and it seems to work the way it should. But, when I change the background color programmatically, it works. That is a strange bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be Bug set color programmatically by

self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

Answer (score 0):

Check backgroundcolor property of Main View and set it as per your need.